# Не получается подключиться к google play game servises : Ошибка Failed to sign in. Please check your network connection and try again

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, google-play-games

Пишет при попытке подключения Ошибка "Failed to sign in. Please check your network connection and try again." Работаю в Андроид студио.

Comment: Метки (теги) нужны для того, чтобы выделить основные моменты ВОПРОСА, по которым другие пользователи быстрее смогут найти решение аналогичной проблемы, а не для демонстрации собственных предпочтений в выборе IDE. Вопрос никак не связан с проблемами при работе IDE Android Studio и этот тег в вопросе не нужен.

Comment: Хорошо, Я понял